Is there a generalized quantum teleportation for n-qubit entangled states?
Quantum teleportation for single qubit is a fairly simple algorithm to follow. Even its extensions into the transportation of $n$ qubits is fairly simple: repeat the process $n$ times (or run $n$ iterations simultaneously), as seen here.
I'm looking for an algorithm for transporting an entangled state in $H^{\otimes n}$.
To take the (presumably) simple case, let us say I want to teleport $\alpha|00\rangle+\beta|11\rangle$ to another party. I do not know the coefficients. How would I go about doing it? Having a circuit representation would be ideal.
Once that is covered, what about the quantum teleportation of an unknown state entangled over $n$ qubits?

I believe the post from the link you shared answers your question. You just repeat the protocol for each of the qubits. Even if they are entangled, the state Bob ends up with is the one Alice had at the beginning of the process. The example shared in that post is for an entangled pair.

@diemilio It is, I got my calculations wrong. I'll add my corrected workings as an answer shortly.

@AlanWhitteaker I don't understand the point you're making about merging. If you think you can focus this post to differentiate it enough from the linked one (and without invalidating current answers) you are encouraged to edit it, which will cue the post to be reopened. If you want to add something to the discussion in the linked post, you are free to do so regardless of the status of this one

@glS I'll edit this post then.

As mentioned in the link shared the the OP, a simple way to extend the teleportation protocol to $n$ qubits is to basically replicate the teleportation procedure for each of the qubits. This works even if the state to be teleported is entangled.
However, for sake of clarity, I am posting a separate answer here since the example given in the original post is specifically for 2 qubits, uses deferred measurements, and shows the answer in terms of measured probabilities, which is not a guarantee that the state was teleported with the correct phases.
The Qiskit code below works for an arbitrary number of $n$ qubits. The only adjustment needed is to make sure the list used to define the state ψ is of size $2^n$ and represents the normalized probability amplitudes of a valid statevector.
# imports

import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, transpile
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector, partial_trace
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

# Number of qubits
n = 3

# Arbitrary amplitudes to prepare state |ψ⟩ = α|001⟩ + β|010⟩ + γ|100⟩
α = np.sqrt(1/6)
β = np.sqrt(2/6)
γ = np.sqrt(3/6)

# Prepare arbitrary state vector
ψ = [0,α,β,0,γ,0,0,0]

# Define quantum registers
qrA = QuantumRegister(n, name="A")
qrE = QuantumRegister(n, name="E")
qrB = QuantumRegister(n, name="B")

# Define classical register
cr = ClassicalRegister(2*n, name='M')

# Compose quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(qrB, qrE, qrA, cr)
qc.prepare_state(ψ,qrA, label="$| \\psi \\rangle$")

qc.save_statevector('ψin')

for i in reversed(range(n)):
    qc.h(qrE[i])
    qc.cx(qrE[i],qrB[i])

qc.barrier()

for i in reversed(range(n)):
    qc.cx(qrA[i],qrE[i])
    qc.h(qrA[i])
    
qc.barrier()    
qc.measure(qrE,cr[0:n])
qc.measure(qrA,cr[n:2*n])

for i in range(2*n):
    if i < n:
        qc.x(qrB[i]).c_if(i,1)
    else:
        qc.z(qrB[i-n]).c_if(i,1)

qc.save_statevector('ψout')

# Transpile circuit
sim = AerSimulator()
qc_t = transpile(qc, sim)

# Run Sim
result = sim.run(qc_t).result()

# Extract Statevectors
ψin = result.data().get('ψin')
ψout = result.data().get('ψout')

# Trace out syndrome qubits
ρin = partial_trace(ψin,range(0,2*n))
ρout = partial_trace(ψout,range(n,3*n))

# transform back to statevector
ψin = ρin.to_statevector()
ψout = ρout.to_statevector()

print('State prepared by Alice:')
display(ψin)
print('State received by Bob:')
display(ψout)

This code produces the following circuit to teleport 3 qubits:

and generates the following output, which shows that the state Bob receives matches the state Alice prepared:
State prepared by Alice:
$ \frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} |001\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} |010\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} |100\rangle $
State received by Bob:
$ \frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} |001\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} |010\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} |100\rangle $

Teleportation does not break entanglement. That means that for a general entangled state over $n$ qubits
$$
(\alpha \left|{\psi}\right\rangle\otimes\left|{0}\right\rangle + \beta \left|{\psi'}\right\rangle\otimes\left|{1}\right\rangle)_A
\underset{\text{Teleportation}}{\longrightarrow}
\alpha \left|{\psi}\right\rangle_A \otimes\left|{0}\right\rangle_B + \beta \left|{\psi'}\right\rangle_A \otimes\left|{1}\right\rangle_B
$$
with $\left|{\psi}\right\rangle$ and $\left|{\psi'}\right\rangle$ being an $n-1$ qubit state.
Perform this $n$ times and you can transfer any state in $H^{\otimes n}$.
